# Problems with properly simulate a border to a "ribbon" with css. How do I correct it?

Tags: html, css

After a little quarrel with css I managed to support "ribbons" with minimum IE8 and other browsers. 
Now I wanted to add a border, but I can not get it.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="ribbonEX07">
<a href="#"><span>· TITLE·</span></a>
<div class="ribbonEX07-border"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .ribbonEX07 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid #f2cec2;
    position: absolute;
}

.ribbonEX07:after {
    content: "";
    float:left;
    border:1.5em solid #faefeb;
    border-right-color: transparent;
}

.ribbonEX07 span {
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#faefeb;
    color: #cd3301;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:3em;
    padding:0 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.ribbonEX07-border{
    position: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-width: 15px 10px 25px 35px;
    border-top: 30px solid #f2cec2;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5H5U/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the shadow styles from `.ribbonEX07-border` to `.ribbonEX07-border:after` and that should make it elastic so it can work on long titles.

```
.ribbonEX07-border {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 26px;
}
.ribbonEX07-border:after{
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 29px solid #f2cec2;
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BAkJG/

Answer (score 1):

Change yor style to

```
.ribbonEX07-border{
    position: inherit;
    width: 81%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-width: 15px 10px 25px 35px;
    border-top: 29px solid #f2cec2;
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/L5H5U/4/)

Comment: Thanks but It does not work. Not the solution because if the text grows the edge disappears. The width should always be 100%.